# Is it possible to have variable width of bars in geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2

There is an option to change `fill` and `col` when using `geom_col`
Is it possible to have change width of bars in geom_col  - like in the last line below ?

```
dt <- data.table(diamonds) [ , .(total=.N, price = mean(price)), by = cut]; dt # data.table to work with

ggplot(dt) + geom_col(aes(x=cut, y=price, fill=total))   # we can do this
ggplot(dt) + geom_point(aes(x=cut, y=price, size=total)) # we can do this

ggplot(dt) + geom_col(aes(x=cut, y=price, size=total))   # this does something different
ggplot(dt) + geom_col(aes(x=cut, y=price, width=total))  # this does not work
```

Or what could be a way to achieve the desired output - I need the width of bars be proportional to the `total`.
This is quite a typical  situation:  when you plot anything about data - you need to show the sample size of these data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

ggplot(dt) + 
  geom_col(aes(x=cut, y=price), width = dt$total/100000)
```

Vary the denominator to the width argument to vary the absolute width of the columns.
[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

I accepted the answer above, based on which the code below is written that does that job as needed -  by moving the `width` argument inside aesthetics:

```
dt %>% ggplot(dt) + 
  geom_col( aes(x=cut, y=price, width = total/max(total)) )
```

This is nice because then you can call it in pipeline using `%>%`, as you don't need to specify `dt$` inside the function.

Note however that this generates the warning
`Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: width` (using ggplot2_2.2.1 version), but it does do the job.

[image]