# ggplot() + geom_col(): determining column width with a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Please excuse any issues with this post as it's my first post here; Feel free however to leave constructive criticism.

The following code makes a bar chart using the `titanic` data from the `ggmosaic` package and is an example for something else I am making and wish not to share.

I am trying to figure out how I can edit the width of the columns to match the `Total_In_Class` Variable, Is there a way I can do this? or should I look to create a different visualization of the information?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmosaic)

titanic %>%
  group_by(Class, Sex, Age, Survived) %>%
  tally() %>%
  spread(key = Survived, value = n, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(Classification = paste("Class: ", Class, " Sex: ", Sex, " Age: ", Age)) %>%
  mutate(Total_In_Class = Yes + No) %>%
  mutate(Percent_Survived = Yes / Total_In_Class) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = Classification, y = Percent_Survived)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = Classification, y = Percent_Survived, label = Total_In_Class), vjust = -.3) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, vjust = -.05))
```

[image]

I've tried using the `width` argument in `geom_col()` as well as including `width = Total_In_Class` in the `aes()`, but neither of those worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two approaches:

---

First of all, there is the `geom_col` version described here: [Is it possible to have variable width of bars in geom_col?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355197/is-it-possible-to-have-variable-width-of-bars-in-geom-col?rq=3)

```r
# Let df be the output of you data wrangling pipe

ggplot(df, aes(x = Classification, 
               y = Percent_Survived, 
               width = Total_In_Class/600)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, vjust = -.05))
```

[image: geom_col with variable width]

Take note on the `width` aesthetic. The number you divide by should scale the resulting numbers to something between 0 and 1, because that is somewhat in the scale of distance the labels below the `x`-axis are spaced by. If `width` is something in the hundreds, all `x`-axis ticks will be convoluted into a seemingly single point in the middle, because their distance (1-ish) is tiny relative to the width of the rectangles (100-ish).

---

But, still, I am not quite satisfied with the result. This is not what we wanted, right? We wanted neighboring rectangles neatly arranged. I found out that this kind of plot is called *mosaic plot*. I like to think about them as rectangles that have a metric `x` *and* `y` aesthetic mapping, e.g. their area is showing something about two variables at once. Wherease a `geom_col` can only have one metric mapping, the other must be categorical.

For ggplot, there is `ggmosaic`. The key difference: We can not input already `tally()`ied data, because it is doing the counting internally (like `geom_bar` would do). So we are going back to the original titanic dataset.

First of all, a demo of the more "proportionate" rectangles: (This is literally taken from the `?geom_mosaic` help examples).

```r
library(ggmosaic)
ggplot(titanic) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Class), fill = Survived))
```

[image: mosaic plot of titanic class and survival counts]

This is the more complicated version with all possible classification combinations you requested. It might need some finetuning after familiarization with `ggmosaic`, for example by moving one factor, e.g. `Age` into a separate aesthetic named `conds = Age`.

```r
ggplot(titanic) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Class, Sex, Age), fill = Survived)) +
  # Add rotated x-axis labels for legibility
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, vjust = -.05))
```

[image]

To get back more into the direction you posed your reprex question initially, we can use `ggmosaic` together with the `Classification` variable you created.

```r
titanic %>%
  mutate(Classification = paste("Class: ", Class, " Sex: ", Sex, " Age: ", Age)) %>%
ggplot() +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Classification), fill = Survived)) +
  # rotate x axis labels
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, vjust = -.05))
```

[image: ggmosaic chart of all titanic classification combinations, fill = sex]

This is my favourite, because it achieves what I imagined to be your desired outcome. I think you wanted to use `Survival_Percentage * Total_In_Class` to visualise amount of survivors as the area of the bar.

Percentage is not necessary anymore because `number of survived * Total_in_Class` is giving us the same relative proportion as above, which becomes visible as the rectangle area.